# IntelliJ IDEA crashing , not starting

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I downloaded , Intellij and trying to start or open that , but getting below exception , i did not have any testMe plugin , i just downloaded it from their website , it is community Edition

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.AssertionError: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling; job=UndispatchedCoroutine{Cancelling}@47542153
    at com.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil.getEnvironmentMap(EnvironmentUtil.java:98)
    at com.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil.getValue(EnvironmentUtil.java:192)
    at com.V.L.N.g.Vz.V(Vz.java:146)
    at com.V.L.N.g.E.V(E.java:219)
    at com.V.L.N.g.g_.V(g_.java:197)
    at com.V.L.N.g.g_.V(g_.java:148)
    at com.V.L.N.g.gZ.V(gZ.java:55)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.kt:15)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$startApplication$8$2.invokeSuspend(main.kt:346)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.mainImpl(Main.kt:63)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.mainImpl$default(Main.kt:49)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.kt:46)
    Suppressed: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com.weirddev.testme.intellij.configuration.TestMeConfigPersistent [Plugin: com.weirddev.testme]
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices2(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:854)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:806)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:403)
        at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.registerComponents(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:58)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$initServiceContainer$2.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:197)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$initServiceContainer$2.invoke(ApplicationLoader.kt)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$initServiceContainer$2.invoke(ApplicationLoader.kt)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
        at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span$default(tracer.kt:49)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader.initServiceContainer(ApplicationLoader.kt:196)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader.access$initServiceContainer(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.ApplicationLoader$loadApp$2$initServiceContainerJob$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:86)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
    Caused by: com.intellij.platform.instanceContainer.internal.InstanceAlreadyRegisteredException: com.weirddev.testme.intellij.configuration.TestMeConfigPersistent
        at com.intellij.platform.instanceContainer.internal.InstanceRegistrarImpl.registerInitializer(InstanceRegistrarImpl.kt:32)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices2Inner(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:910)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices2(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:847)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling; job=UndispatchedCoroutine{Cancelled}@47542153
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com.weirddev.testme.intellij.configuration.TestMeConfigPersistent [Plugin: com.weirddev.testme]]

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.9+7-b1087.9 aarch64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
```

I tried to check for plugin testme in my local , but i could not find any such plugin

Comment: Hi. Try following the steps from this troubleshooting guide: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559. It will have you delete certain directories used by the IDE (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) in order to restore program integrity.